# Does a member of a C++ base class really needs to be virtual to be overridden by a derived class?

Tags: c++, polymorphism, virtual, members

```
class A { 
    public: 
    virtual int test()=0; 
};

class B : public A { 
   public: 
   int test(){return 10;}
};


B *b = new B();
b->test(); // would return 10;
```

**whereas:**

```
class A { 
    public: 
    int test(){return 0;}
};

class B : public A { 
   public: 
   int test(){return 10;}
};


B *b = new B();
b->test(); // **would return 0**;
```

Why does it return "**0**" here? This makes zero sense to me, because I assume that the (kind of overloaded) members of the derived class (B) come first!
What is happening here?

Comment: `B->test()` doesn't compile.  What makes you think the second example results in zero?

Comment: Yeah, your conceptions are incorrect. Even if you change the B to b to make it compile, it would return 10.

Comment: Have you tried it? I really don't think it will return 0

Comment: I'm guessing that he is wondering why `A *b = new B()` yields 0, even though the function has been replaced. Someone please explain vtbls to him

Comment: You should review this question and answers, it should clear things up for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2932909/overriding-vs-virtual

Comment: What is happening if you add using B::test; in the class B ? Or if you call it like that: B::b->test();

Comment: its returning 10 check here http://ideone.com/4mzEJO#view_edit_box

Comment: *What is happening here?* The definition of the language in the standard...

Comment: Okay, take a look at this: http://ideone.com/lnmYgE

Comment: This question needs to be either edited or closed, since it isn't actually producing the output as described.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apart from the invalid syntax (`B->test();` where it should be `b->test();`), the second one will also return 10.

If instead you would have written:

```
A* a = new B();
a->test();
```

It would have returned 0 or 10 depending on whether A::test is virtual.

Comment: Go to: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/polymorphism/  and Ctrl+F "varify" and see the above example. Now If I make the base virtual funtion not virtual and allocate "ppoly1" not as a Polygon, but as a CRectangle, it will return 0!

Comment: @user1511417: Take the time to reread the code in the linked page. You will only get the base's implementation if the static type of the pointer/reference is *base*